# encountering error while using reference in recursion

Tags: c++, recursion, pass-by-reference, void

I wrote a code of recursion with two versions. The first one passed parameters by array of array, and had no error. The second one passed reference to vector of vector and the execution stopped in the halfway.
This would be the first version:

```
    #include<iostream>
    #include<vector>
    #include<string.h>
    using namespace std;
    int n,m;
    void bdfs(bool B[202][208],int x,int y,bool v[202][208]) { //passing array of array as recursion's parameter
        if(x < 0 || y < 0 || x >= n || y >= m)return;
        if(B[x][y] != 0 || v[x][y])return;
        v[x][y] = 1;
        bdfs(B,x,y+1,v);
        bdfs(B,x,y-1,v);
        bdfs(B,x+1,y+1,v);
        bdfs(B,x+1,y,v);
        bdfs(B,x+1,y-1,v);
        bdfs(B,x-1,y+1,v);
        bdfs(B,x-1,y,v);
        bdfs(B,x-1,y-1,v);
    }
    int main(){
        n=202;
        m=208;
        bool B[202][208],v[202][208];
        memset(B, 0, sizeof(B));
        memset(v, 0, sizeof(v));
        bdfs(B,0,0,v);
        return 0;
    }
```

And this would be the second version, which had error.

```
    #include<iostream>
    #include<vector>
    using namespace std;
    int n,m;
    void bdfs(vector<vector<bool> >& B,int x,int y,vector<vector<bool> >& v) {//passing reference to vector of vector as recursion's parameter and got error in the halfway
        if(x < 0 || y < 0 || x >= n || y >= m)return;
        if(B[x][y] != 0 || v[x][y])return;
        v[x][y] = 1;
        bdfs(B,x,y+1,v);
        bdfs(B,x,y-1,v);
        bdfs(B,x+1,y+1,v);
        bdfs(B,x+1,y,v);
        bdfs(B,x+1,y-1,v);
        bdfs(B,x-1,y+1,v);
        bdfs(B,x-1,y,v);
        bdfs(B,x-1,y-1,v);
    }
    int main(){
        n=202;
        m=208;
        vector<vector<bool> > B(202,vector<bool>(208,false));
        vector<vector<bool> > v(202,vector<bool>(208,false));
        bdfs(B,0,0,v);
        return 0;
    }
```

I am wondering if there is any problem regarding the misusage of recursion or reference. Please tell me why the second version went wrong.

Comment: Both versions cause the stack to overflow.

Comment: @RawN but I don't quite get why one is working while the other isn't...

Comment: Stunned that you dent see an error in the first one. Every call could be throwing around 350 k onto the stack. You can't do that for long.

Comment: What exactly is the error you're getting?

Comment: I tried both versions and they work fine. I don't see why one would work where the other wouldn't, unless you have a really small stack size.

Comment: @user4581301 Um.. regarding your stunned state, those are *arrays*. The value representation on-call is a converted pointer to type (in this case pointer to `bool[208]`). They're not eating 350K per call. Nowhere *near* it in fact.

Comment: Yeah, not thinking. Not sure why I'm even still up.